# UISearchBar above UICollectionView, how can I get it working with only item in the collection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

I have a `UICollectionView` that contains a grid of objects. Above it, in a `UICollectionView` `sectionHeader` I have a `UISearchBar`. I want the search bar to be hidden when the view loads. I try to do it with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // 44 = height of search bar.
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44) animated:YES];
}
```

This works when the `collectionView` contains many objects, when the `scrollView` have `scrollIndicators`. But when I e.g. only have one item this doesn't work, the `searchBar` is always visible. I wonder which approach is the best for achieving my goal, display the `UISearchBar` when the user scrolls down?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't know a fix, but I know that by default, UICollectionView disables scrolling until the content is larger than the screen.  That could be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display `UISearchBar` even user scrolling down down then you can do this by:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    UISearchBar *tempSearchBar = searchDisplayController.preSetSearchBar;
    CGRect rect = tempSearchBar.frame;
    rect.origin.y = MIN(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    tempsearchBar.frame = rect;
}
```

And if you want to hide it then you only need to use:

```
[scrollView alwaysBounceVertical:YES]; // allows always bounce to vertical
```

It is the default behave if `UIScrollbar` So by setting value it pretends to collection view that it has some more height then view.

From reference:

> If this property is set to YES and bounces is YES, vertical dragging
>   is allowed even if the content is smaller than the bounds of the
>   scroll view. The default value is NO.

Comment: Should the searchBar be placed inside a section header, or not?

Comment: @Anders It should work in `sectionHeader`. Also you can do `searchbar.hidden = YES` by check condition `self.collectionView.contentSize = someRequiredSize;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this problem because of your content collectionView size. Try to increase it before you set contentOffset:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.collectionView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44) animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your header view by setting it's size to zero

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (headerIsActive == NO) 
        return CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    else 
        return CGSizeMake(768, 44);
}
```